# How to link GridView controls across <asp:Content> placeholders?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am learning ASP.NET and I have a master-detail scenario using two GridViews in ASP.NET 3.5 and C#. GridView grdOrders lists a set of orders and the GridView grdOrderDetails lists a set of order details for an order. I have a master page which defines two content areas with this code:

```
<div class="leftColumn">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphLeftSide" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="rightColumn">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphRightSide" runat="server" />
</div>
```

On my orders.aspx content page I have put the grdOrders GridView in the cphLeftSide content placeholder and GridView grdOrderDetails in the cphRightSide placeholder with code like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="leftContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphLeftSide" runat="server">
    <h2>Orders</h2>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdOrders" DataSourceID="sdsOrders"...></asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsOrders" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csOrders %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_GetOrders" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

In the rightside I have the orderDetails content with code like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="rightContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphRightSide" runat="server">
    <h2>Order details</h2>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdOrderDetails" DataSourceID="sdsOrderDetails"...></asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsOrderDetails  runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csOrders %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_GetOrderDetails" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="orderId" ControlID="grdOrders" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:Content>
```

When I run my code I get this error:

> Server Error in '/Test2' Application.
>   Could not find control 'grdOrders' in ControlParameter 'orderId'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'grdOrders' in ControlParameter 'orderId'.

How do I connect the two data sources? So that when I select an order, it runs the usp_GetOrderDetails stored procedure and binds to the grdOrderDetails GridView? The code runs fine if I put both GridViews and DataSources in the same

```
<asp:Content>
```

tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Order gridview is selected (whatever the event is called -- onSelected or something), do this in your code-behind:

- sdsOrderDetails.parameters("orderID").defaultvalue = grdOrders.selectedvalue

That's just psuedo, but hopefully clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="orderId" ControlID="cphLeftSide$grdOrders" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
</SelectParameters>
```

That's Because your problem is in the refer parameter can't find the "grdorders" so you can use $ to make the parameter look in the other content place holder on the same page

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that springs to mind is to do it in code behind. Within `Page.Init`, try:

```
grdOrders.DataSource = sdsOrderDetails
```

Likewise, you will most likely have to enumerate your select parameter collection and associate the control explicitly.

**Update:** You could even try ommitting the ID attribute of the `<asp:content>` controls, Visual Studio might complain but theres a good chance that they won't behave as naming containers as a consequence.